# String starting with hyphen minus fails with whiptail

Tags: bash, whiptail

I have this simple script displaying msgbox using whiptail.

```
#!/bin/bash

str="-|foo\n"
whiptail --title "test" --msgbox "$str" 20 78
```

When I run this script I get error:

```
-|foo\n: unknown option
```

If I make change

```
str="+|foo\n"
```

then it succeeds.

Anyway I can circumvent this without changing `str`? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `whiptail` manpage (which should be available with the command `man whiptail`; if not, you can read it [here](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/whiptail.1.html)) contains this note (in the **Notes** section):

> `whiptail` interprets arguments starting with a dash "`-`" as being arguments.  To avoid this, and  start  some  text  in, for example, a menubox item, with a dash, whiptail honours the `getopt` convention of accepting the special argument "`--`" which means  that  all  following arguments with dashes are to be treated verbatim and not parsed as options.

Answer (score 0):

I can just use textbox instead.

```
whiptail --title "test" --textbox foo.txt 20 78
```